# Installing Docker on AWS EC2 Free Tier account

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS cloud.
Want to install docker on the ec2 instance.
I have done the following steps.

- Created aws free tier account
- Launched ec2 instance
- Now trying to install docker by command `sudo yum install docker -y`
  But getting the response as following:
  [image]

Following is the memory status:
[image]

Kindly suggest what needs to be done.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of top command

Comment: did my solution worked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is that your instance has `983 mb memory out of which 857 mb is already used.`
Left over memory is 63 Mb which is very `less for system even to do yum install operation that is why you are getting this error`.

if you run `top`  or `htop` command, you will be able to see which process is eating up your memory. Once you find the process note its PID (process id).

to pause

```
kill -TSTP $PID_OF_PROCESS
```

then run your `yum install`.Once done resume your process which you paused.

to resume

```
kill -CONT $PID_OF_PROCESS
```

Comment: Thank you Jatin, I `ps aux --sort -rss` command to list all the process in order by killed ones coming more momory